# Create Object using ObjectBuilder

Tags: c#

Want to create objects using ObjectBuilder or ObjectBuilder2.

I do not want to use **StructureMap**

I was able to create the object having parameterless constructor using the code mentioned below.

```
 public class ObjectFactory : BuilderBase<BuilderStage>
    {
        public static T BuildUp<T>()
        {
            var builder = new Builder();

            var locator = new Locator { { typeof(ILifetimeContainer), new LifetimeContainer() } };

            var buildUp = builder.BuildUp<T>(locator, null, null);
            return buildUp;
        }
```

for creating object of customer you just call

`ObjectFactory.BuildUp<Customer>`

However this creates object of class which has no parameters, however I need to create object which are having constructor with parameters.

Comment: Do you know what arguments you need to pass for types without default parameters? Or you would like to figure out what the arguments are, provide their values and call constructor using those values?

Comment: Why beat yourself over the head?  Unity.  Definitely.

Comment: @decyclone: The parameters can be anything. Also there can be parameters which can be injected Using Web Client Software Factory.

Comment: I will agree with `Will`. Use `Unity` or any other `IoC` container for dependency injection.

Comment: @decyclone: Will not be able to use Unity as already spring.net and WCFS is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the CreateNew Attribute class to build the object and that worked fine. Also used the SessionStateBindingStrategry so that the object could take session variables as parameters in the constructor.

```
  public static T BuildUp<T>()
            {
                var locator = new Locator { { typeof(ILifetimeContainer), new LifetimeContainer() } };
//For accessing the session variables through StateValue<>
                 locator.Add(new DependencyResolutionLocatorKey(typeof(ISessionStateLocatorService), null), new SessionStateLocatorService());

                var builder = new Builder();

                var attribute = new CreateNewAttribute();
                IParameter parameter = attribute.CreateParameter(typeof (T));

                builder.Strategies.AddNew<SessionStateBindingStrategy>(BuilderStage.PreCreation);

                var builderContext = 
                    new BuilderContext(builder.Strategies.MakeStrategyChain(),locator,builder.Policies);
                object value = parameter.GetValue(builderContext);

                return (T)value;
            }
```